# 'Validation of viewstate MAC failed' problem, no load-balancing, cluster or server farm

Tags: .net, viewstate, mac-address

This is a particularly unhelpful and difficult issue that we're experiencing with a number of sites. These are reasonably high-traffic and complex sites, but they're all on the one box - there's no load-balancing or web farm going on. It's very hard to reliably reproduce but any ideas about potential fixes would be appreciated.

Just to emphasise, the problem happens very intermittently (maybe 1 in a 100?) and at this stage I can't isolate any particular action on the site causing the problem.

The only genuine solution we can think of is converting the sites to MVC, but as you can imagine this is a really big task.

Sites are built in .NET3.5, are obviously web forms based, hosted on a box running Windows Server 2008 standard, 32-bit, IIS7, application pools runing in 'Classic' mode.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details about the lead up to the error. It is too broad a question for me to figure out anything. I usually see this error with improper cross page posting.

Comment: I am doing what I can to get that extra info, believe me. I'll add more info as soon as it comes available.

Comment: MAC validation also fails if someone modifies the ViewState (hence the reason for using a MAC in the first place). Have you ruled out that the failures aren't due to a scanning tool or intentional manipulation by the user? The app would be expected to fail on something like "__VIEWSTATE=1" or "__VIEWSTATE=<script>...". That's a different issue than internally-generated errors.

Comment: The problem is certainly occurring when users are doing a postback to submit a form; i.e. not when just viewing content. We have enough information from our client's user base to rule out any deliberate manipulation of the viewstate. Is it a possibility that the user is just submitting the form quickly, before the entire viewstate has come through in the initial response?

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce this error by leaving the login form for a long time then filling in the form and hitting submit. After searching for 'viewstate expire' and reading around a bit more I've had a go at manually setting the `<machineKey ... />` element in my Web.config, if it works I'll put it in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to reproduce this error by leaving the login form for a long time then filling in the form and hitting submit. After searching for 'viewstate expire' and reading around a bit more I've had a go at manually setting the  element in my Web.config.

The specific element to add to your Web.config file is:

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey
    validationKey="EEF33150A048D162D22CB36E1CB9956B148C7A4E6999D0F05B53D416D7A16F83823DD626F501DD3549D3E5DCB473634739D0AD9A07F71560946498C943A7586D"
    decryptionKey="0E95F75864047EB6322EA7D5246F2C1175D77A1B016F293C3BAAD000299A3DC8"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

The values in the `validationKey` and `decryptionKey` attributes are just randomly generated hex numbers, but need to be exactly 128 and 64 bytes respectively.